# How to disable Scroll Effect in WPForms Plugin Form WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am using WPForms plugin with a Multipage Form. But the thing is When I click NEXT on an empty required field the page scrolls down I don't know why. How to disable scrolling effect. Please help

Link: https://platinumcapitalconnect.com/
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may try as below:

```
function wpf_disable_multipage_scroll() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.wpforms_pageScroll = false;</script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wpforms_wp_footer', 'wpf_disable_multipage_scroll' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Disable scrolling on error and submissions.


function wpf_dev_disable_scroll_effect_on_all_forms( $forms ) { 
    foreach ( $forms as $form ) {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            wpforms.scrollToError = function(){};
            wpforms.animateScrollTop = function(){};
            </script>
            <?php
            
    }
}
add_action( 'wpforms_wp_footer_end', 'wpf_dev_disable_scroll_effect_on_all_forms', 10, 1 );`enter code here`
```